# Is possible record only audio or only video with vlcj?

Tags: java, vlcj

I'm newbie using vlcj and would like to know what options could be used to record audio only. In another situation, record only video.

I'm recording audio and video together, using the options below, but the project requires providing options to record audio or video regardless.

```
String[] options = {
":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp1v,vb=4096,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{mux=mpeg1,dst=" + fileName + "},dst=display}", ":input-slave=dshow://hw:0,0" };
```

I searched in google and also in stackoverflow, but have not found a solution for this specific case.

I appreciate any help possible.

Tks,

acsnrj

Answer (score 0):

You can specify "dummy" for the video or audio codec.

This vlcj example transcodes only audio:

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/vlcj-2.4.1/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/rip/RipAudioTest.java

The relevant code from that example is:

```
mediaPlayer.playMedia(args[0], "sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,channels=2,ab=192,samplerate=44100,vcodec=dummy}:standard{dst=" + args[1] + ",mux=raw,access=file}");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add "--no-video" option to `playMedia` function to avoid processing video.